# How to make to variables to subtracted each other in python

Tags: python

I was trying to make a basic RNG combat, so people could just copy and paste it and use for their games at our school but I need help on one part.

```
import random
print("Your Weapon's Stats")
print("         /^\\        ")
print("         | |         ")
print("         | |         ")
print("         | |         ")
print("         | |         ")
print("         | |         ")
print("       \\\=*=//      ")
print("          |          ")
print("         (+)         ") 
print("(+)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(+)")
print(" | Damage:         | ")
print(" | 1-9             | ") 
print(" | Attack Speed:   | ")
print(" | 6/10            | ")
print(" | Critical Chance:| ") 
print(" | 64%             | ")
print("(+)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(+)")
your_damage = random.choice("12345789")
enemy_health = 20
enemy_health - your_damage <---it says that not right so what do I do?
print(enemy_health)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `-=` operator to subtract `your_damage` from `enemy_health`:

```
enemy_health -= your_damage
```

This is equivalent to writing `enemy_health = enemy_health - your_damage`.

You also want to change `random.choice("12345789")` to `random.randint(1, 9)`. This selects a random integer between `1` and `9` inclusive, thus ensuring that `your_damage` is a number instead of a string.

Your code should be:

```
import random

print("Your Weapon's Stats")
print("         /^\\        ")
print("         | |         ")
print("         | |         ")
print("         | |         ")
print("         | |         ")
print("         | |         ")
print("       \\\=*=//      ")
print("          |          ")
print("         (+)         ")
print("(+)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(+)")
print(" | Damage:         | ")
print(" | 1-9             | ")
print(" | Attack Speed:   | ")
print(" | 6/10            | ")
print(" | Critical Chance:| ")
print(" | 64%             | ")
print("(+)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(+)")

your_damage = random.randint(1, 9)
enemy_health = 20
enemy_health -= your_damage

print(enemy_health)
```

Comment: Oh i also want to add critical hits how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually assigning your new value to `enemy_health`, so you want to do this:

```
enemy_health = enemy_health - your_damage
```

Which can be simplified using the `-=` operator.

So:

```
enemy_health -= your_damage
```

To comment about your usage of `random.choice`. You are almost correct in what you are trying to do, however, you want to use a list of integers instead of a string of numbers. So you can do this instead:

```
random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Even nicer:

```
random.choice(range(1, 10))
```

Comment: THK :DDD that does make it neater :D thanks so much =D